# "Divisions" feature and query response times

Tags: ldv, division

From an LDV perspective, SFDC mentions [Divisions](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Webinar:_Extreme_Salesforce_Data_Volumes_%282013-Feb%29) are a way to speed up query response times:

> Divisions... make searches, reports, and list views more meaningful to users in
> very large organizations by segmenting data into logical sections. For
> example, if your searches are taking a long time or timing out, and
> your users only need to see a subset of your data, then using
> Divisions can help improve performance.

I understand the user-experience when using [Divisions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000329515&type=1&mode=1)... simple enough. Useful. But technically, how does this feature work?

Is this a prioritized custom index that the platform maintains?

EDIT: OP's links are dead, I think this is what the links were:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000329515&type=1

Comment: Salesforce being based on Oracle, I suspect this is using [partitions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/bigdata-appliance/overview/index.html).

Comment: but custom indexes are expensive in terms of insert/update. They actually have a technical downside. Do "Divisions" have a downside or a tradeoff? I want to know... but to answer this I need to know what they are... their quiddity. All I know is what they are probably NOT... I do not think they have anything to do with Share Tables or Group Maintenance Tables, for example. I think @PhilW might be right. But then my next question is "ok, so what is the downside to using Partitions"? Is there a con or tradeoff?

Comment: My question would be: will your users notice any technical (performance) downside? Remember, you are running in the cloud on virtualized servers using a proprietary, multi-tenant platform. The UX has arbitrary latency anyway (entirely based on what your neighbours are doing) and you don't otherwise pay for CPU usage as such (just limited to a certain amount per transaction).

Comment: If you tell us _why_ you care about the underlying implementation or (better) what you're trying to achieve, you'll probably see more useful answers.

Comment: Old question but since this is a Q&A site, regardless of what OP was looking for it would be helpful to understand what divisions do on the back-end as a community

Comment: @krigi i like the way you are thinking about this... did you ever get an answer to this q?   also as an aside, you inspired this question - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/386267/how-do-custom-indexes-impact-performance-negatively

Comment: no answer to this one. I'll be sure to update if I do track one down.